# Pandas txt file to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file that contains these log entries:

```
-------------------> 2020-03-04 14:41:11.578 
Unable to process update. Multiple Entries
<------------------- 2020-03-04 14:41:16.000
```

I am trying to get a column for each line:

```
start_time            event_desc                    end_time
2020-03-04 14:41.00    Unable to process update    2020-03-04 14:41:16.000
```

I have tried this code:

```
log_list = []
with open(path_to_file) as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        log_list.append(line)
df_log = pd.DataFrame(log_list, columns=['log_entries'])
df_log['start_time'] = df_log['log_entries'].str.extract(r'(?<=^\-{19}\>)\s(P<start_time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3})')

df_log['event_desc'] = df_log['log_entries'].str.extract(r'(^\w.+)')

df_log['end_datetime'] = df_log['log_entries'].str.extract(r'(?<=^\<\-{19})\s(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3})')
```

This works but the even description is not in line with the start and end times. I have thought to drop the NA rows, but I think there might be a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: from your regex this is probably true, but are the entires always between arrows? `-->[your_data]<---`

Comment: yes, the entries will always be between arrows.

Comment: Is there exactly one description line between a start and a stop?

Comment: Correct, always one description between start and stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the file at parse time instead of using `read_csv` because the file is not in csv format:

```
start = re.compile(r'(?<=^\-{19}\>)\s(?P<start_time>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3})')
end = re.compile('(?<=^\<\-{19})\s(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3})')
word = re.compile('(^\w.+)')
data = []

for line in io.StringIO(t):
    match = start.search(line)
    if match:
        row = {'start_time': match.group('start_time')}
        data.append(row)
    else:
        match = end.search(line)
        if match:
            row['end_time'] = match.group(1)
        else:
            match = word.search(line)
            if match:
                row['event_desc'] = match.group(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['start_time', 'event_desc', 'end_time'])
```